# Navigation Drawer menu item click not working

Tags: java, android, firebase

**I have used Navigation Drawer, Bottom Navigation bar, and a custom Action bar.**

**Bottom navigation bar and action bar are working fine. The navigation drawer also shows a menu present under it but the items are not clickable.**

### I have tried all the answers related to

but still, my problem has not been solved yet. there is no error in the debug section.

[Navigation Drawer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfHaz.jpg)
[MainActivity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzLTc.jpg)

**Activity Main XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/purple_500"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel"
            app:itemTextColor="#3F51B5"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.PathShalaInstitute.PopupOverlay" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Menu XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_video"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_video" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logOut"
            android:icon="@drawable/log_out"
            android:title="@string/log_out" />
    </group>


    <item android:title="Upcoming">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/soon"
                android:title="Coming Soon" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity Java**

```
package com.laksyaindia.pathshala;



import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.laksyaindia.pathshala.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.laksyaindia.pathshala.hamburger.ui.videos.VideosFragment;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavController navController;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        navigationView = binding.navigationView;
        bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigationView;
        Toolbar toolbar = binding.toolbar;
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.navigation_home);


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);

        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home,
                R.id.navigation_test,
                R.id.navigation_batches,
                R.id.navigation_feed)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView user = headerView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView gmail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.gmail);
        database.getReference().child("Users").child((Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())))
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String name = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("username").getValue()).toString();
                        String email = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("mail").getValue()).toString();

                        user.setText("Hello ! " + name);
                        gmail.setText(email);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        if (itemId == R.id.navigation_home) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have selected Home...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (itemId == R.id.nav_video) {
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation_home, new VideosFragment()).commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have selected Video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (itemId == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Slideshow...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else if (itemId == R.id.nav_logOut) {
            auth.signOut();
            Intent logOut = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(logOut);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have been logged out successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else if (itemId == R.id.soon) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Coming soon...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Navigation drawer menu item click not working

Comment: So your question is not related to Firebase, right?

Comment: Yes my question is not related to firebase